# Vulnerable web apps for testing session identifier prediction

Tags: session-management

I want to learn testing session identifier strength. So I need a web application with this type of vulnerability and run the app locally. I've tried WebGoat, but I need some other web apps known to have weak session identifier. Do you know any web apps with this vulnerability?